# Counting vowels in a function

Tags: python, list, for-loop, function

I just needed some help with a function for counting vowels, the function is made to return a list of words that have more vowels than consonants.

```
def moreVowels(text):
    vowels = 'AEIOUaeiou'
    words = text.split()
    returnList = []
    for word in words:
        vowelCount = 0
        for letter in word:
            if letter in vowels:
               vowelCount += 1
        if vowelCount > len(word)/2:
           returnList.append(word)
    return returnList

mlk = 'Our lives begin to end the day we become silent about things that matter'

print(moreVowels(mlk))
```

when I print the function, it returns the words twice, not sure why.

```
['Our','Our','about','about']
```

Comment: Seems ok, how are you calling the method?

Comment: In fact, that `mlk` var doesn't have an `Our` word, so you're doing something wrong something else or just a typo.

Comment: you could also reduce your vowels to one case (lower for instance) by replacing `if letter in vowels:' with `if letter.lower() in vowels` -- just an idea

Comment: Note that your `returnList.append(word)` line isn't indented like it should be.  This is often a sign that you're mixing tabs and spaces, which can cause confusion about how deeply lines are actually indented.  If your `if vowelCount > len(word)/2: returnList.append(word)` were *actually* (not just in appearance) indented one level deeper, that's the output you'd get (typo aside).  Try running your program using `python -tt yourprogramname.py` to check.

Comment: the 'out' was a type error.
and the way I printed was:
    print(moreVowels(mlk))

Answer (score 2):

As you have it posted it works correctly.  But, if I change the indentation of the vowel count `if` statement like so:

```
def moreVowels(text):
    vowels = 'AEIOUaeiou'
    words = text.split()
    returnList = []
    for word in words:
        vowelCount = 0
        for letter in word:
            if letter in vowels:
               vowelCount += 1
            if vowelCount > len(word)/2:  #indent changed
               returnList.append(word)    #indent changed
    return returnList
```

I get the same results as you did.  Check the indentation in your source and remember don't mix tabs and spaces.